# autocapitalize not working

Tags: javascript, android, html

On mobile devices using a custom keyboard it seems that it does not follow the rules set:

```
<input type="text" autocapitalize="off">
```

I assume this is a bug, I wonder if there is a JavaScript` solution to such a problem. But, if I used js to force lower case this is a rather bad user experiencing?

But how can I fix this? So that the user needs to click the shift button on their keyboard (mobile keyboard)

Seen here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textarea width height: 22px (or more).

```
<textarea style="height: 22px" ...></textarea>
```

Comment: holly molly, i'm trying this out now. If it works whoppie. No sadly it is still starting with a capital letter.

Comment: you can use key event methods and when a user keydown you can convert it to what you need with programmatically

Comment: Indeed, sadly this is what I am doing and shortof keyup its very slow. Also what if the user holds the keydown....